# Ставить ли запятую в СПП с союзом «и»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, спп, и

*Я рад, что так случилось **и** мы победили.*
Такой пример предложения. Нужна запятая перед И или не нужна? Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Это же не ССП, а СПП.

*Я рад, что так случилось (и что) и мы победили.*

У нас есть главное предложение и два придаточных. По-иному не читается.

Answer (score 1):

[§ 109. Пунктуация в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными](http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxviii.html#sect109):

> Между однородными придаточными предложениями, соединенными неповторяющимся соединительным или разделительным союзом, запятая не ставится, например: *Чудилось, будто корчуют сразу весь лес **и** выдираемые из земли корни и сама земля стонут и вопят от боли* (Федин) (повторяющихся союзов здесь нет: первый союз *и* соединяет два придаточных предложения, второй – два однородных подлежащих *корни* и *земля*, третий – два однородных сказуемых *стонут* и *вопят*); *Что это за соединение **и** кто такой Ковпак, мы тогда ещё не знали* (Медведев).

*Я рад, **что** так случилось **и*** [**что**] *мы победили.*
Главное предложение "я рад", союз "что" во втором предложении подразумевается (то есть придаточные однородны). Запятая перед "и" не ставится.

При другой структуре предложения запятая нужна:
*Я рад, что так случилось, и не жалею о сделанном выборе* (из статьи).